# Alternatives to SoundPlayer

Tags: wpf, soundplayer

I'm using the `SoundPlayer` class to play WAV files in my WPF application.  The files are short and are part of the application and are played in response to events that occur in the program.  The user has no control over what sound is played and can't decide to play a sound on their own.  I've also tried using the WPF `MediaPlayer` control, but I had problems with that control.  The `SoundPlayer` is working great, but there's a problem.

Essentially, I need to keep a queue of sounds and play the sounds one after the other as they queue up.  In some circumstances, I have to stop whatever sound is playing and play another sound instead.  So I have two requirements which turn out to be mutually exclusive with the `SoundPlayer` control:

1. My code needs to know when a sound has finished playing.
2. The sounds have to play in the background

To implement this, I created a class called `SoundController`.  This has a background thread and it uses the `Thread`'s  `Dispatcher` to queue up calls to a method that I use to play the sounds, using `BeginInvoke`.  The method raises an event in the `SoundController` event before it calls `SoundPlayer.PlaySync` to play the sound, and then it raises another event after `PlaySync` returns.

In my UI thread, at the point where I need to stop the sound, I call the `SoundController` class's `Stop` method.  This calls the `SoundPlayer`'s `Stop` method to stop playing the sound.  And here's where the problem happens.  It turns out that `SoundPlayer.Stop` does NOT stop the sound, but it waits for the sound to finish before returning.

This stops my GUI dead. While I could call it asynchronously, my GUI won't stop but the sound won't stop, either.

As I said, the WPF MediaPlayer didn't work for us and it was overkill, anyway.  Is there any other alternative for playing sounds that will give me the ability to raise events, play the sound in a background thread, and stop the playback?

Edit 06/26/2012:

This has been out here for over a month and I've gotten no responses.  So I guess there are no other alternatives to the `SoundPlayer` control.

I'm going to post a new question coming at the problem from a different angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were no responses to this question and I've moved beyond this.  So, for anyone who's wondering, the alternatives are the `MediaElement` WPF control and making WIN32 API calls.

So which alternative did I use?  Neither.

It turned out that for me, I had to add a second thread to my `SoundController` class.  The second thread does not run a `Dispatcher`; instead, it runs code I wrote in a loop:

1. It initially waits indefinitely on an `AutoResetEvent`.
2. When the `AutoResetEvent` is raised, it starts a while loop that checks to see if a sound is to be played.
3. If a sound is to be be played, it does so.
4. It loops around and if another sound was "queued" while the last sound is playing, it plays that sound.
5. This repeats until there are no sounds queued to be played.

There's a little bit more but it doesn't matter.  In any event, this seems to work OK.  Because the sounds are playing on a separate `Thread`, the currently playing sound can be aborted from a different `Thread` by calling the `SoundPlayer.Stop` method.

**EDIT:**

Here is a stripped down version of my code.  I removed some things that were particular to my program's requirements that had to do with a special sound. This shows how the basic process works.

```
private string NextSound { get; set; }
public AutoResetEvent PlayASoundFlag = new AutoResetEvent( false );
private Dictionary<string, SoundPlayer> Sounds { get; set; }
private object soundLocker = new object();
public string SoundPlaying { get; private set; }
public bool Stopping { get; set; }

public void PlaySound( string key, bool stopCurrentSound ) {
    if ( !Sounds.ContainsKey( key ) )
        throw new ArgumentException( string.Format( "Sound \"{0}\" does not exist", key ), "key" );

    lock ( soundLocker ) {
        NextSound = key;
        if ( SoundPlaying != null && stopCurrentSound )
            Sounds[ SoundPlaying ].Stop();
        PlayASoundFlag.Set();
    }
}

private void SoundController() {
    do {
        PlayASoundFlag.WaitOne();
        while ( !Stopping && NextSound != null ) {
            lock ( soundLocker ) {
                SoundPlaying = NextSound;
                NextSound = null;
            }
            Sounds[ SoundPlaying ].PlaySync();
            lock ( soundLocker )
                SoundPlaying = null;
        }
    } while ( !Stopping );
}
```

When your program starts up, the class loads keys & sound files into the `Sounds Dictionary`. That way, all the user has to do is pass the key for the sound they want to play to the `PlaySound` method.

If you wanted to, you could replace the `NextSound` property with a `Queue`. The `PlaySound` method would have to enqueue the key of the sound to be played and the `SoundController` thread would have to dequeue each key from the thread in the `while` loop, exiting when there's nothing left in the `Queue`.

Finally, when your program stops, you need to set the `Stopping` flag to true & set the PlayASoundFlag so the code comes out of the loop. That will cause the `SoundController` thread to stop.

I leave initializing the `Dictionary` and starting the thread to you.

Comment: I've just run into this precise issue with a winforms app rather than WPF, but I doubt that matters in this case. I'm a little unclear on why/how adding a second worker thread would make a difference here (either `.stop()` works cross thread, or it doesn't surely? Why does *which* thread it is matter?) I'm going to come back to this tomorrow or Monday to try and wrap my head around it but if you have the time/motivation to elaborate on this and/or put it into skeleton code I'd be very grateful :-)

Comment: The problem is that the thread that calls the `Play` method can't interrupt itself, since it's busy playing the sound. It can't possibly execute a call to `Stop` until after it's done playing the sound, and by then it's too late. The only way to stop a sound that's in the middle of playing is to call `Stop` from a different thread.  That's why I added a separate thread that's dedicated to doing nothing but playing sounds. I'll edit my answer and add some skeleton code.

Comment: I call PlaySync on a new thread but calling Stop from the UI thread (in response to button click) has no effect (it still waits for the sound to complete, blocking my UI the entire time). Calling Stop from a third thread also did not change that behavior. Using async/await also had no effect. Has anyone gotten this solved?

Comment: @LutzKretzschmar: If the Stop method isn't working, I think you'd have to stop the thread that's playing the sound.